# Value Error in PCA - Principal Component Analysis

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am trying to implement Principal Component Analysis (PCA) as per this document here - https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/principal-component-analysis/. All works well until I reach this -

```
# Make a list of (eigenvalue, eigenvector) tuples
eig_pairs = [(np.abs(eig_vals[i]), eig_vecs[:,i]) for i in range(len(eig_vals))]

# Sort the (eigenvalue, eigenvector) tuples from high to low
eig_pairs.sort()
eig_pairs.reverse()

# Visually confirm that the list is correctly sorted by decreasing eigenvalues
print('Eigenvalues in descending order:')
for i in eig_pairs:
    print(i[0])
```

This throws a value error -

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Maybe the you do not have the latest version of numpy? I am using 
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)  and  Numpy version 1.11.1 and it works for me.

Comment: @BChow My python version is 2.7.13 and numpy version is 1.12.1